# How to optimize ImageMagick CPU usage on server

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, imagemagick, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to overlap an image on top of another image using ImageMagick. I set up an AWS beanstalk machine with 16 core cpu with 32gb ram(c5 4x large) and am running the code in a Go environment. Whenever a GET request hits the server, the following shell command gets executed.Here's the command that I'm running

```
cmd := "convert "+ img1 + " -page +"+fmt.Sprintf("%.1f", offsetX)+"+"+fmt.Sprintf("%.1f", offsetY) + " " + img2 + " -background none -flatten "+outputFilePath
cmdout,err := exec.Command("sh","-c",cmd).CombinedOutput()
//convert img1.png -page +10+10 img2.png -background none -flatten  output.png
```

img1 is of size around 500x500 and im2 is around 200x200

I performed a load test and found out that the current setup can only handle 15 requests/second with a cpu usage of 51%. At 25req/sec, the cpu usage becomes 95%. I strongly believe there's something that I'm doing wrong. I'm using Imagemagick v6.7.8. Would upgrading to latest version or compiling ImageMagick from source (instead of yum install) help?

What should I be doing inorder to meet 100req/sec and make sure all vCPU's are optimally utilized

Comment: Why do you believe you're doing something wrong? What is your reason for thinking performance should be better?

Comment: Note that there are (faster) alternatives to imagemagick. And starting an external process for each request is not always the best solution.

Comment: @Flimzy C54XLarge is a powerful instance and we were able to achieve a maximum of 15 requests per sec. I think there may be some tweaks which I think I am missing to achieve higher requests per sec.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. Why do you think you should be able to handle more than 15 req/sec?

Comment: @DenysSéguret I am planning to use graphics magick if this doesn't work out . I am open for alternate suggestions as well

Comment: That aside, though, Denys makes good points. You could probably achieve a big performance boost by doing batch processing, by binding directly to the imagemagick library (see this package: https://github.com/gographics/imagick), or by using a faster alternative.

Comment: The simplest optimization, though, would probably be not to start _two_ processes. You're calling 'sh -c imagemagick ...'. Why not just 'imagemagick ...', and skip the intermediate shell?

Comment: @Flimzy That makes sense. Will try removing the intermediate shell and use the imagemagick library

Comment: did you try imagemagick with -opencl enabled ?

Comment: That version is probably around 6 years old, I would consider upgrading.

Comment: Do you have any information as to what the content of the files is? I mean is it cartoons, photos, computer-generated graphics? Could you save the combined file as JPEG maybe?

Comment: This is an excellent application for AWS Lambda which will allow you to handle many more operations for a lot less money

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried on my 2015 i5 laptop (two core, four thread). I made some test data like this:

```
$ mkdir sample
$ cd sample
$ vipsheader ../fg.png ../bg.png 
../fg.png: 200x200 uchar, 4 bands, srgb, pngload
../bg.png: 500x500 uchar, 4 bands, srgb, pngload
$ for i in {0..1000}; do cp ../fg.png fg$i.png; done
$ for i in {0..1000}; do cp ../bg.png bg$i.png; done
```

So 1,000 500x500 and 200x200 PNG images.

First, the base case (IM 6.9.10):

```
$ time for i in {0..1000}; do convert bg$i.png -page +10+10 fg$i.png -background none -flatten out$i.png; done
real    0m49.461s
user    1m4.875s
sys 0m6.690s
```

49s is about 20 ops/second.

Next, I tried with GNU parallel. This is a simple way to run enough of them in parallel to keep all cores loaded:

```
$ time parallel convert bg{}.png -page +10+10 fg{}.png -background none -flatten  out{}.png ::: {0..1000}
real    0m32.278s
user    1m46.428s
sys 0m11.897s
```

32s is 31 ops/second. This is on a two-core laptop -- you'd see a better speedup with a larger desktop machine.

Finally, I wrote a tiny [pyvips](https://pypi.org/project/pyvips/) program to do your task. pyvips is the Python binding for [libvips](https://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/), but there are Go bindings too.

```
import pyvips

for i in range(0, 1000):
    bg_name = "bg" + str(i) + ".png"
    fg_name = "fg" + str(i) + ".png"
    out_name = "out" + str(i) + ".png"

    bg = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(bg_name, access="sequential")
    fg = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(fg_name, access="sequential")

    result = bg.composite2(fg, "over", x=10, y=10)

    result.write_to_file(out_name)
```

I see:

```
$ time ~/try/try289.py 
real    0m25.887s
user    0m36.625s
sys 0m1.442s
```

26s is about 40 ops/second. You'd be able to get it a bit quicker if you ran several in parallel.

One of the limits you are hitting is the PNG format -- the library is single-threaded, and rather slow. If you are willing to try TIFF, you can get quite a bit more speed.

TIFF with deflate compression is functionally similar to PNG. If I try:

```
$ vips copy fg.png fg.tif[compression=deflate]
$ vips copy bg.png bg.tif[compression=deflate]
$ ls -l bg.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 19391 Dec 27 20:48 bg.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 16208 Jan  2 18:36 bg.tif
```

So it's actually slightly smaller, in this case. If I change the pyvips program to be:

```
bg_name = "bg" + str(i) + ".tif"
fg_name = "fg" + str(i) + ".tif"
out_name = "out" + str(i) + ".tif[compression=deflate]"
```

And run it, I see:

```
$ time ~/try/try289.py 
real    0m17.618s
user    0m23.234s
sys 0m1.823s
```

About 55 ops/second.

Comment: pyvips worked out pretty well. What format would you suggest considering most of my input images have transparency(AFAIK jpeg does not support transparency)

Comment: tiff can hold losslessly-compressed images with an alpha channel, and it's much faster than PNG. I'll update the answer with some timings.

Comment: Change `try289.py` so it can read range from command line, and then combine with GNU Parallel?

Comment: I tried, but on this two-core laptop, it didn't help that much, down from 25s to 23s. It would probably have more of an effect on a large desktop or server machine.